# MySQL order by first element of array in row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have problem with ordering of my table by row with prices array.
Below example rows:

```
1) ;100
2) ;50
3) ;50;100;300
4) ;30;150
```

**I want to order by first element of array.** When I order by price row ASC I get:

```
1) ;100
2) ;30;150
3) ;50
4) ;50;100;300
```

It is wrong result because "100" should be last...
I tried:

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`price`, ';', 2), ';', 1) AS INT(3) ASC
```

But still wrong... Any clue?

Comment: you should normalize your table design, which would essentially make this problem go away.

Comment: I cannot modify this base's structure... Any idea to improve ORDER?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close.  If I were doing this I would use (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f57af/6/0)

```
 ORDER BY 0+TRIM(LEADING ';' FROM price)
```

This works by getting rid of any semicolon, then (via the `0+` trick) treating the initial characters of the `price` column as an integer, not as text.

You could also do

```
ORDER BY 0+SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val,';',2), ';', -1)
```

or

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val,';',2), ';', -1) AS INTEGER)
```

You had two problems. First, your outer `SUBSTRING_INDEX` operation needed a third parameter of -1.  Second, you cast as `INTEGER`, not `INT(3)`.